# ftp configuration tool

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I have a small LAN at home - 4 computers.

3 machines run Ubuntu and one has Windows.

I want to use one of my Ubuntu machines as a LAMP server. I want to have different users from their own machines (within the LAN) uploading some files to specific folders on the server.

I've already (unsuccessfully) tried vsftpd. I'm not so good at it for one thing, and the other is that I don't find it very convenient.

**The question:**
Is there a tool I can use to create accounts and assign users/folders more easily? The ideal thing would be like what we use on cpanel.

As for client users, they would be on FileZilla.

The 'server' in question is Ubuntu Desktop 11.10

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason to use FTP in your LAN instead of more common and easier-to-manage Samba server?

Comment: I agree with Alexander ,just share the folders with people you want to have acces to them over the lan

Comment: I'm trying to create a working model for team-based php development. So if User "John" is working on project X, I want him to be upload files to /var/www/X/John. Likewise another user in a different folder. And if John is on another project called Y, he'd need to upload files into /var/www/Y/John. This is the reason I need to setup FTP accounts at various times and also remove them the moment a user no longer needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Windows FTP with the help of IIS.

or you may try File Zila FTP tool to make FTP.

Else if you are in LAN you can use file folder Sharing if you are in the same Network.

Comment: Thanks Pwawan, but I don't think this will fit the bill. I've put Windows behind me for some time now.